# JavaFX ToggleGroup not functioning properly with accelerators (RadioMenuItem)

Tags: javafx

I am working with a JavaFX Menu with several RadioMenuItems. These items are in a toggle group, and work correctly when clicked with a mouse. I need hotkeys on these items, and would like them displayed in the dropdown, so added accelerators. These work as well, but if the hotkey combination for an already selected item is used again, that item is deselected, leaving no selected options in the ToggleGroup. The desired behavior would be to leave the item selected if the same combination is used again.

I've tried several versions of trying to catch when the ToggleGroup selected value is null, but since the deselect call always fires before the select call, there is no way to know whether the deselect call is valid or not for manually overriding the behavior.

FXML snippit

```
<Menu >
    <RadioMenuItem fx:id="item1" text="item 1" >
        <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="theToggleGroup" />
        </toggleGroup>
        <accelerator>
            <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="d" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
        </accelerator>
    </RadioMenuItem>
    <RadioMenuItem fx:id="item2" text="item 2" toggleGroup="$theToggleGroup">
        <accelerator>
            <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="b" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
        </accelerator>
    </RadioMenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Java

```java
theToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> doStuffBasedOnSelectedToggle(newValue));
// null pointer on newValue when nothing is selected (should never happen in a ToggleGroup)
```

Alternatively, I tried to set the

```
onAction="#doStuffBasedOnSelectedToggle"
```

in the FXML, but the problem remains that if you select the same one twice, it is deselected instead.

Mimic this behavior with the above code by going back and forth between hotkey 'Ctrl+B' and 'Ctrl+D' with no issues. Issue arises with 'Ctrl+D' followed by 'Ctrl+D' again, or 'Ctrl+B' followed by 'Ctrl+B' etc.

If there's no fix for this / not supported operation in Java for some reason, I can change to CheckMenuItem and do a manual implementation of Toggle functionality, but that seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I found to not have issues is a change to the onAction of each RadioMenuItem. This needs to happen in the Java, not in the FXML.

```java
item1.setOnAction(event -> {
    item1.setSelected(true);
    doStuffBasedOnSelectedToggle();
}
item2.setOnAction(event -> {
    item2.setSelected(true);
    doStuffBasedOnSelectedToggle();
}
```

With this code, they appropriately toggle back and forth, and will not toggle off if the same one is selected twice.

The root cause of the original problem seems to be buried in the Java library

```
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContralAcceleratorSupport.java -> doAcceleratorInstall(...)
```

This method handles RadioMenuItems and CheckMenuItems identically by toggling them. The correct behavior would've been to toggle CheckMenuItem and set RadioMenuItem to true.

Comment: Consider [submitting a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) if one doesn't [already exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8213225?filter=allopenissues) (also see [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx)).

Comment: I've filed an issue here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8237505